# Rails App search bar works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

EDIT: Not a duplicate of ["Why doesn't this query work on Heroku?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135375/why-doesnt-this-query-work-on-heroku). Search does not involve strings, only date queries.

Rails App throws no errors locally when searching but throws an error every time when searching on prod. This used to work fine. I'm developing against SQLite3 and haven't changed anything directly interacting with the search bar recently. I rolled back to some pretty old branches to make sure; it was still broken. I've got SQLite3 running on 1.3.9, specified in my gemfile.

Here is the search def from my model:

```
def self.search(search)
   where("startDay LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

The view:

```
<%= form_tag(weeks_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <h4>Search for weeks by start date </h4>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Weeks", value: Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday) - 7 %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Anything else I should include that might help solving the issue?

Comment: Doesn't involve strings, that fix was to make the search case insensitive :/ Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is not about searching for strings or dates. The problem is that your local database is different from production one. PostgreSQL can't apply `LIKE` operation directly on datetime fields, it should be explicitly converted to a string before using a string operation. Without switching to production type database in your development environment you will continue obtaining similar kind of bugs in future.

In postgresql this query should be written as follows:

```
 where("startDay::text LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: I understand that it's not in good practice to have different dev and prod databases but I don't understand why switching over now would resolve the issue. This code hasn't been modified in months and was working previously despite the databases always being different...I'll try your suggestion but I'm unclear as to exactly why swtiching would solve my issue.

Comment: You're not switching to solve the issue, you're switching to prevent future issues from occurring.

Comment: Gotcha. So this isn't a solution to the issue, just a suggestion to prevent clashing between the two databases? Any ideas regarding how to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in the future.
I switched to postgreSQL, but because my app is 99% complete, I decided that rather than trying to go back through my files and change all of my syntax I would abandon Heroku, continue to use sqlite3 and instead host my own production server.